# Find items and repetitions in list

Tags: python, list

I am working in Python and considering the following problem: given a list, such as `[1, 0, -2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 3]` which contains the integer 0 multiple times, I would like to have the indices at of these 0 and for each one, the number of times it appears in the list until a different element appears or the list ends.

Given `l = [1, 0, -2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0]`, the function would return `((1, 1), (3, 2), (7, 1))`. The result is a list of tuples. The first element of the tuple is the index (in the list) of the given element and the second is the number of times it is repeated until a different element appears or the list ends.

Naively, I would write something like this:

```
def myfun(l, x):
    if x not in l:
        print("The given element is not in list.")
    else:
        j = 0
        n = len(l)
        r = list()
        while j <= (n-2):
            count = 0
            if l[j] == x:
                while l[j + count] == x and j <= (n-1):
                    count +=1
                r.append((j, count))
                j += count
            else:
                j += 1
        if l[-1] == x:
            r.append((n-1, 1))
        return r
```

But I was wondering whether there would be a nicer (shorter?) way of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Not the prettiest, but a one-liner:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l=[1, 0, -2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0]
>>> [(k[0][0],len(k)) for k in [list(j) for i,j in itertools.groupby(enumerate(l), lambda x: x[1]) if i==0]]
[(1, 1), (3, 2), (7, 1)]
```

First, `itertools.groupby(enumerate(l), lambda x: x[1])` will group by the second item of `enumerate(l)`, but keep the index of the item.

Then `[list(j) for i,j in itertools.groupby(enumerate(l), lambda x: x[1]) if i==0]` will keep only the 0 values.

Finally, the last list comprehension is needed because `list(j)` consume the itertools object.

Comment: Indeed, it can be done in one line with `itertools`. I'll look into this library. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Another oneliner with [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), without using intermediate lists:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = [1, 0, -2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 3]
>>> [(next(g)[0], 1 + sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(enumerate(l), key=lambda x: x[1]) if k == 0]
[(1, 1), (3, 2), (7, 1)]
```

In above [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) will return `(index, value)` tuples which are then grouped by the value. `groupby` returns `(key, iterable)` tuples and if key is nonzero the group is discarded. For kept groups [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#next) is used to pull out the first item in the group and take index from there while rest of the items are processed by generator expression given to [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum) in order to get the count.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do this

```
l=[1, 0, -2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0]
lis=[]
t=0
for m in range(len(l)):
    if l[m]==0: 
        if t==0:
            k=m
            j=1
            t=1
        else:
            j=j+1
            t=1
        if m==len(l)-1:
            lis.append((k,j))
    else:
        if t==1:
            t=0
            lis.append((k,j))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

L = [1, 0, -2, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0]

res = []
i = 0
while i < len(L):
    if L[i] == 0:
        t = len(list(takewhile(lambda k: k == 0, L[i:])))
        res.append((i, t))
        i += t
    else:
        i += 1

print(res)
```

The line

```
t = len(list(takewhile(lambda k: k == 0, L[i:])))
```

counts the number of zeroes there are from the current position to the right.

While clear enough, the disadvantage of this solution is that it needs the whole list before processing it.